# To make people get used to and accept the bad by showing them the worse

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am searching for an idiomatic expression for making people accept and get used to what they normally wouldn't by showing or making them experience a worse one.

Edit; when authority wants to increase a price of a 100x to be 150x but doesn't want to face trouble with people, they first make it 200x and after bad reactions it reduces the price to be 150x and make people happy with it.

Comment: It'd help if you included a real-world example of what you mean.

Comment: I'm sure there's a term at least for when politicians do this, for instance saying "We're going to abolish all social security for the unemployed", and then when they announce cuts to social security, everyone is relieved that it's not being abolished. I can't remember what it's called, it's not quite a [dead cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_cat_strategy) or [wag the dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wag_the_dog).

Comment: @StuartF Are you thinking of the "Overton Window"?

Comment: I have trouble thinking of a real-world example, which may be why no idioms come to mind.

Comment: It's population management 101.

Comment: BTW, you likely mean increases of 100%, not 100x. A 100% increases from $10 goes from $10 to $20. A 100x increase goes from $10 to $1,000.

Answer (score 0):

This is often done by making a comparison.

> You think that's bad? It's not as bad as X.

> At least it's not X.

Where "X" is replaced with the worse situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of “**problem-reaction-solution**” in which a problem is created = (the excessive price with the intention of escalating fear or opposition), then offering a pre-planned solution (a high price that nevertheless is less than that originally stated.)

The same manipulation can be made in the opposite direction:

The workman quotes £2,000 for the job that he says will take a week. He knows that £2,000 is excessive and that the job is easy. He finishes the job in 3 days and announces the “good news” that he will only charge £1,500. Three days and £1,500 is a fair price and time, but the workman benefits from the excellent publicity he will receive.

It is also known as The Hegelian dialectic.

> “Hegelian dialectic, or problem, reaction, solution. This method basically involves fabricating or intensify a problem, offering a draconian solution, then settling for a “compromise” that nevertheless furthers the intended goal.” *― Jim Marrs, Our Occulted History: Do the Global Elite Conceal Ancient Aliens?*

The problem with “problem-reaction-solution” is that it is strongly (but not always) associated with conspiracy theories.